# Is there a way to justify text in a PBI DAX measure?

Tags: text, powerbi, dax, whitespace, justify

I have a text box in PBI whose title is set to a measure value as shown below:

```
dense test = 
var seperator = "|"
var a = "some set of value:"
var a1 = 1100
var a2 = 240000
var b = "some other set of value:"
var b1 = 2300
var b2 = 15000

var alltogether = 
a & a1 & seperator & a2 & UNICHAR(10) &
b & b1 & seperator & b2 
RETURN alltogether
```

word wrap is off
title is set to a function -> the measure value
alignment = left

[image]
what I'm struggling with is I cannot get the pipe seperator to align I've tried padding with REPT() function but it seems as though the textbox decides arbitrarily how much space to add after  each variable.

```
dense test rept = 
var seperator = "|"
var a = "some set of value:"
var a1 = 1100
var a2 = 240000
var b = "some other set of value:"
var b1 = 2300
var b2 = 15000

var alltogether = 
a & REPT(UNICHAR(127),25 - LEN(a)) & a1 & seperator & a2 & UNICHAR(10) &
b & REPT(UNICHAR(127),25 - LEN(b)) & b1 & seperator & b2 
RETURN alltogether
```

Results below:

[image]

Comment: you can show text and value in separate text box/card with no border. Then place border around the whole thing so that it looks like a single card. this way you can alighn you texts as required.

Comment: Brilliant! an excellent and simple solution. Worked